# Create an AWS AMI for Ubuntu with GUI which automatically launches web browser

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I've got an ubuntu AMI setup with ubuntu desktop installed and Chrome installed and set to boot on load (via the startup programmes menu within the ubuntu desktop)

I've created an image of this AMI, but any time I launch a new instance running this, the Ubuntu GUI doesn't seem to load, until I SSH into the machine, enable VNC and then connect via Chicken VNC to the machine. At that point, the desktop appears to load + starts the browser.

I really need the machine to boot and the browser to load without having to VNC into the machine.. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does not provide any kind of KVM console for EC2 instances. Given this fact, the only possible methods to access to your servers are network based (usually SSH, VNC or RDP).

I recommend you to setup VNC service to autostart and use it to connect to your instance.